# angular/ionic: unknown provider, error result of injector unable to resolve a required dependency

Tags: angularjs, controller, dependencies, ionic-framework, router

I seem to be having an issue regarding an $injector being unable to resolve a dependency.

The error received is: Unknown provider: itemsProvider <- items <- ItemListCtrl

I have looked at the samples on this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=itemsProvider%20%3C-%20items%20%3C-%20ItemListCtrl

However, it seems that my code doesn't seem to have the same issue as there are no controller within controller dependencies or usage of services/directives.

Can anyone spot what's wrong?

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider       
 .state('app.items', {
        url: '/items',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/item-list.html',
                controller: 'ItemListCtrl'
            },
        }
    })
```

Controller

```
    .controller('ItemListCtrl', function($scope, $log, $stateParams, items) {

            items.getItems(function(items) {
                $scope.items = items;
                //console.log(items);
            });
        })
```

From index.html

```
     <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/items">
          items
     </ion-item>
```

Factory method:

```
    angular.module('starter')
    //Factory


        .factory('items', function($http) {
```

Comment: The last argument of the controller function is named `items`. So, Angular needs to inject `items`in the controller. What is it supposed to be? Where is it supposed to come from? It must either be a service, or a member of the `resolve` param of your state.

Comment: @JBNizet  Sorry, I edited the code. Items is sent by the factory

Comment: You probably forgot to include the script containing the items service in the html file.